# Specify monitor diagnostic settings 'send interval'

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-diagnostics, azure-monitoring

I am wondering how I can increase the frequency in which azure monitor sends diagnostic settings to eventhub. I am using the diagnostic settings in a Redis resource to forward metrics to an eventhub. From there they are ingested by a custom monitoring `stack`.

The diagnostic is set via :

`az monitor diagnostic-settings create -n eh-meh \
--resource $REDIS_ID --event-hub redis-metrics \
--event-hub-rule $EH_RULE_ID \
--metrics '[{"category": "AllMetrics", "enabled": true, "timeGrain": "PT1M"}]'`

Metrics appear in the eventhub but only every `5` minutes. I came across [the azure diagnostics schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/azure-diagnostics-schema-1dot3-and-later)  which mentions `scheduledTransferPeriod` but setting this in the metrics doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot increase the frequency for diagnostic settings.  Each resource provider (in your case Redis) is responsible for emitting the events and so you may observe some services emitting events more frequently than others.  Generally speaking though, for now, the latency is about 5 minutes.

The `scheduledTransferPeriod` you referenced is not applicable to the Redis service, hence the reason it didn't change anything.